# Why is my actual download speed less than that found by by speedtest.net?

Tags: internet, download, bandwidth

I ran my Internet connection through SpeedTest.net which claims that it finds out the actual Internet speed, much lower than that promised by my ISP.

But—while downloading—the speed is much lesser than the test results. Even after using download mangers like Internet Download Manager, there isn’t much difference.

Are some background apps consuming my Internet bandwidth? If so, how can I divert all of the bandwidth towards one application?

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on where you're downloading from anyway? Have you done tests to various download servers?

Comment: Doubtful that anything running in the background is affecting your download speed any significant amount. What is the difference in speeds between your speedtest result and your actual download speed? Are you doing both at the same time of day? What is it you're trying to download?

Comment: I am downloading from a local ftp server, I don't think the speed should vary much.

Comment: @PaulHay the difference is around 5 times.

Comment: Sorry, you are comparing speedtest.net results to a local ftp download?

Comment: This definitely wouldn't be caused by apps running in the background. I would suggest testing your connection by trying to download things from elsewhere and seeing what d/l speeds you get then. If it's still low, then your ISP may be throttling your connection when it detects you using too much bandwidth during peak hours, there isn't much you can do about this bar changing providers.

Comment: @RanveerAggarwal - By a local FTP server do you mean within your network, if so, then your ISP has NOTHING to do with that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Are you sure you got control of BITS and BYTES?

When testing your speed with speedtests online, you're measuring BITS per second. When downloading files, your speed is in BYTES per second. As there is 8 bits in a byte - Your download speed "should" equal your speedtest-result /8.

Getting 8mbps on speedtest, would give you 1MB/s download-speed.

Also check your sources. (Local-FTP???)
You should also run different speedtests to verify a result. You will almost never get a 100% correct answer by running a speedtest, but it will give you a pointer.

To answer the question - there is software to monitor your computers bandwidth use, but it's not likely that's the culprit.

My guess is mixed terminology if you say the speed is 5 times higher on speedtest.

Addition: I just did a speedtest on speedtest.net. 
In my example, I "should" get a download speed of 32,5MB/s. Now - with that speed there are other things limiting downloads (like disk-speed+++) but it should give me a pointer of what I could expect with hardware that supports it.

[image: Speedtest]

Comment: Is there a website that can test your MEGABYTES per second[Mb/s]? instead of Mbps?

Comment: Would you want to test the network only, or the complete setup? As in disks ect.?

Answer (score -1):

To test your ACTUAL download speed, you can go to http://speedtest.tweak.nl/.
It generates a binary file on-the-fly, so no matter how fast your line, you will always get what is possible with YOUR connection, not limited by the remote server.

For traffic monitoring you could use one of the many free network monitors out there, to find out, which application produces how much traffic.

As for bandwith shaping, I do not know any free/open software that does this; they all cost money, afaik.

Comment: This seems like spam for the website. You don't indicate the reason the author requires paid software to fix a problem caused by his ISP and/or old wiring in his house.  The speed historically advertised by your ISP is in theory the highest speed, its not even the average speed, its a burst speed.  This is the case at least in the US.

Comment: @Ramhound That is why I said he can use a FREE traffic monitor to check IF the problem lies with applications on his system, and in this case use NL, BECAUSE i do not know of any software that does bandwidth shaping for free.

Comment: I know dozens of free alternatives to that piece of software.  We don't even know what the actual problem is.  I can justify an upvote on this answer because of the bad advice.